# Which one is better to use for list item?

Tags: html, xhtml

Suppose I have ten list item, in that case I can use both div and li to display them one after another. But my concern is which one will be better approach in page loading perspective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantically, if you have items in a list `<li>` is how they should be marked up.

Comment: And also it will probably render faster.

Comment: @Elad Lachmi why would it render faster? Because `li` is one character less than `div`?

Comment: That one I wanted to know which one will render faster. Thanks for the answer....

Comment: @Elad Lachmi: I'm also curious about that reasoning. Not discrediting, just curious.

Comment: What Radek said is one good reason, but I`m guessing it`s not the only one. I`m think this has something to do with the DOM standard, in IE7 at least. I know this from empirical tests we did a while back on IE7 comparing these two and thier load times.

Answer (score 1):

use `<li>`, they are semantically more correct. furthermore, if you use `<ul>` or `<ol>` (or `<dl>`) you can only have `<li>` as child elements

Answer (score 0):

I would use list items, as they're intended for grouping various items into... well, lists. If you don't actually want it to look like an ordered (numbered) `<ol>` or unordered (bulleted) `<ul>` list, then you can always use CSS to style the graphics out.